# jquery - enable the text field when check box is checked

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

```js
$("#owncar").click(function() {
  if ($(this).is(':checked')) {
    $("#carnumber").attr('disabled', false);
  } else {
    $("#carnumber").val('');
    $("#carnumber").attr('disabled', true);
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<tr>
  <td>Have own car :</td>
  <td>
    <input type="checkbox" name="owncar" id="owncar" value="Y" />
  </td>
</tr>

<tr>
  <td>Car Number :</td>
  <td>
    <input type="text" name="carnumber" id="carnumber" maxlength="10" disabled/>
  </td>
</tr>
```

When user ticked check box from have own car, enable car number text field to let user to fill in the car number. 
The above code is OK for me. 
Is there any other ways to enable text field when the checkbox is clicked?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [`prop()`](http://api.jquery.com/prop/) to set the `checked` status of the checkbox. To set the value of the textbox use [`val()`](http://api.jquery.com/val/#val-function) with callback.

```
// Use change event on the checkbox
$("#owncar").change(function() {
    // Cache checked status
    var checked = this.checked;

    // If checkbox is checked, enable the textfield
    // else disable
    $("#carnumber").prop('disabled', !checked).val(function(i, oldVal) {
        // If the checkbox is not checked, then empty the value
        return checked ? oldVal : '';
    });
});
```